# Проверка, что файл скачался

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пишу автотест и мне надо дождаться пока файл скачается, как это сделать с использованием Selenium. Если не используя его, то какой оптимальный вариант? Использую браузеры Firefox и Chrome.

Comment: Разве FF не использует расширение .part, а хром .tmp?